# Thonny Python while loop - output "flashing"

Tags: python

I have a test program I am working on. I am using a Raspberry Pi 4B running Thonny Python controlling an HT16K33 LED Driver via I2C.

My code right now is simple:

```
import board
import time
from adafruit_ht16k33.matrix import Matrix8x8
i2c = board.i2c()
matrix = Matrix8x8(i2c)
i = True
while i:
     matrix.fill(1)
     time.sleep(5)
     matrix.fill(0)
     time.sleep(2)
     matrix[0,0] = 1
     matrix[4,4] = 1
     time.sleep(5)
```

What I expect to see from my LED matrix is the entire grid come on, hold for 5 seconds, then clear for 2 seconds, then 2 specific LEDs come on for 5 seconds, and repeat.

What I am seeing is the entire matrix fill in, flash empty, then fill in again, flash empty, then the 2 specific come on, go out, come back, then the entire matrix fill again. Sometimes I may get 2 or 3 flashes at a state, sometimes just once, but it does not "hold" the pattern.

I am trying to make the output of the HT16K33 more stable and hold the outputs and not flash or cycle.

Thank you in advance for your help.